# Q is to prove that integer just above ($\sqrt{3} + 1)^{2n}$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}$ for all n belongs to natural numbers.

Tags: proof-explanation, binomial-coefficients, alternative-proof, binomial-theorem

Q is to prove that integer just above($\sqrt{3} + 1)^{2n}$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}$ for all n belongs to natural numbers.

In Q , by integer just above means that:
For an example , which is the integer just above 7.3 . It is 8. Then , Q wants you to prove that 8 is divisible by $2^{n+1}$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2 n}=(4+2 \sqrt{3})^{n}=2^{n}(2+\sqrt{3})^{n}\\
=2^{n}(2+\sqrt{3})^{n}=2^{n}\left[^n C _{0}2^{n}+^n C_{1} 2^{n-1} \sqrt{3}+^n C_{{2}} 2^{n-2} \sqrt{3}^{2}+\right.\\
\begin{array}{l}
(\sqrt{3}-1)^{2 n}=(4-2 \sqrt{3})^{n}=2^{n}(2-\sqrt{3})^{n} \\
=2^{n}(2-\sqrt{3})^{n}=2^{n}\left[{ }^{n} c_{0} 2^{n}-n_{C}, 2^{n-1} \sqrt{3}+{ }^{n} c_{2} 2^{n-1} \sqrt{1}^{2} \ldots\right.
\end{array}\\
I+f+f)=2^{n}\left[2(\text { Integer) }]=2^{n+1}\right. \text { . Integer }\\
I+1=2^{n+1} \text { . Integer }
\end{array}
\end{equation}

In the image is the way this question is solved.

My Q from this method of solving is that if we notice at the end , we somehow got $ 2^{n+1}$. If the Q has taken some other value like $3^{n+3}$ or Something else. Then , it was not possible to prove this question.

What is another method to prove this Q or can you help me justify that the above method can be used for all kinds of Q.

Thank you.

Comment: What does "divisible" mean here?  Those numbers are not integers in the usual sense.  Do mean "divisible as elements of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$"?  Something else?

Comment: Please try to type out your question via MathJax, instead of linking pictures. This is because pictures aren't indexed by search engines.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Ok. I’ll type it out in math jax. It is just that for this picture , it would be quite difficult.

Comment: Take it as a question which you have solved. Next time for a similar question you try this method it may or may not work again.

Comment: @lulu I’ll explain that part in the Q.

Comment: @ZAhmed I know only one method. If it doesn’t work , I will lose marks in my exam.

Comment: Examiners often ask a question that can be done like tis.

Comment: @ZAhmed Ok. I got your point from examiners point of view. But from mathematics point of view or a view with which a formula has to be in such a way that is applicable to all aspects. That is much more interesting right. Here , what I didn’t link is that  taking $2^n$ in brackets and then solving. Something like that is only for a particle Q. I hope you get my point. I don’t mean to be against your point of view. Thanks.

Comment: Post edit...so you meant to say $\lceil (1+\sqrt 3)^{2n}\rceil$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}$?  (where, as usual, $\lceil x\rceil$ denotes the ceiling function...the least integer $≥x$).  That's a big omission.  Toward that end, I suggest you look at the sequence $a_n=(1+\sqrt 3)^n+(1-\sqrt 3)^n$ and try to find a helpful recursion.

Comment: @lulu No . The integer just above $(1+\sqrt3)^2{2n}\rceil$

Comment: That notation refers to the ceiling function.  That is, $\lceil x\rceil$ means the least integer $≥x$.  It's standard notation.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: @lulu K. I got this. But how can we solve the Q.

Comment: I told you.  Look at the recursion I mentioned.  It follows rapidly.

Comment: Ok. I’ll check that.

Comment: @lulu So , you mean that for any ceiling function like x. It’s least integer is x?.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  By definition, the ceiling $\lceil x\rceil$ is the least integer $≥x$.  Thus $\lceil \pi\rceil =4$ and $\lceil 2\rceil =2$.  Similarly, the floor function, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer $≤x$.  So $\lfloor \pi\rfloor=3$ and $\lfloor 2\rfloor=2$.

Comment: @lulu I’m sorry but I’m not getting how do you mean to compare it with my Q. Do you mean say to take ceiling function of sqrt 3 + 1 ^2n

Comment: Please just try.  To repeat my earlier hint, first let $a_n=(1+\sqrt 3)^n+(1-\sqrt 3)^n$.    Find a recursion satisfied by the $a_n$.  Prove that $a_{2n}=\lceil (1+\sqrt 3)^{2n}\rceil$.  Then just playing with the recursion is enough.

Comment: Should add:  the posted solution, from @MarkBennet,   follows the same  argument I am proposing. .  As a (very minor) variant, I might suggest that it saves a little time to also consider the sequence $A_n=a_{2n}$ and to find a recursion satisfied by the $A_n$.   But it all comes down to the underlying recursions.

Comment: @lulu Ok. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $0\lt \sqrt 3 -1 \lt 1$

Now look at the numbers $a=1+\sqrt 3, b=1-\sqrt 3$ with $a+b=2, ab=-2$ which are roots of the quadratic $x^2-2x-2=0$

Then with $v_n=a^n+b^n$ we have $v_{n+2}-2v_{n+1}-2v_n=0$ (spot the coefficients) or $v_{n+2}=2(v_{n+1}+v_n)$ now $|b^n|\lt 1$ and indeed $0\lt b^{2n}\lt 1$ so the difference $v_{2m}-a^{2m}=b^{2m}$ is small and positive.

It will be found that $v_n$ is an integer close to $a^n$ for all $n$, and the sign of the difference for even indices is right, and you can run an induction to complete the proof.

If you understand this you will be able to do the same trick with  $A=a^2$ and $B=b^2$ to get a rather simpler induction.

For these kinds of questions with powers of an irrational number "miraculously close" to integers, there is very often a recurrence to be found lurking in the background.

---

If $a$ and $b$ are the roots of $x^2-px+q$=0 and we put $u_n=Ca^n+Db^n$ we can reason as follows:

$$a^2-pa+q=0$$ because $a$ is a root. Multiply through bay $a^n$ to give $$a^{n+2}-pa^{n+1}+qa^n=0$$

Now multiply through by the constant $C$ $$Ca^{n+2}-Cpa^{n+1}+Cqa^n=0$$

Similarly with the other root $b$ and the constant $D$ $$Db^{n+2}-Dpb^{n+1}+Dqb^n=0 $$

Now add these last equations to obtain $$Ca^{n+2}+Db^{n+2}-p\left(Ca^{n+1}+Db^{n+1}\right)+q\left(Ca^n+Db^n\right) = 0 = u_{n+2}-pu_{n+1}+qu_n$$

And this works for any constants $C, D$ and hence for $C=D=1$.

---

We can also argue that $p=a+b$ and $q=ab$ so that

$$u_{n+2}-pu_{n+1}+qu_n=$$$$=Ca^{n+2}+Db^{n+2}-(a+b)Ca^{n+1}-(a+b)Db^{n+1}+abCa^n+abDb^n=0$$ because the terms all cancel.

Comment: $v_n$ or $v^n$ . Also , why n+2? Didn’t understand how $2v_n+1$ ?

Comment: If you meant like$ a^2 $, then it is 1 + 3 + 2*sqrt3

Comment: @SrijanM.T. I am using $v_n$ with $n$ as an index simply to index the terms (so this is not a power), and $A=a^2=4+2\sqrt 3$ with $B=b^2=4-2\sqrt 3$

Comment: How did you get v_n+2 , 2v_n+1 -2v_n

Comment: @SrijanM.T I got that from the quadratic - it is absolutely standard in recurrence relations/difference equations - the recurrence is associated with a polynomial - here a quadratic, which has the same coefficients. I've added some material at the end of the answer so you can see how it follows through. If the two roots are equal something slightly different happens.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is that [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nPlD.jpg) was a bit obscured and so the transcription was a bit off. Here is a more accurate transcription with tags added for reference:

> $$\require{cancel}
> \left(\sqrt3+1\right)^{2n}=\left(4+2\sqrt3\right)^n=2^n\left(2+\sqrt3\right)^n\tag1
> $$
> $$
> \!\!\!\!I+f=2^n\left(2+\sqrt3\right)^n=2^n\left[{}^nC_02^n+\cancel{{}^nC_12^{n-1}\sqrt3}+{}^nC_22^{n-2}\sqrt3^2+\dots\right]\tag2
> $$
> $$
> \left(\sqrt3-1\right)^{2n}=\left(4-2\sqrt3\right)^n=2^n\left(2-\sqrt3\right)^n\tag3
> $$
> $$
> f'=2^n\left(2-\sqrt3\right)^n=2^n\left[{}^nC_02^n-\cancel{{}^nC_12^{n-1}\sqrt3}+{}^nC_22^{n-2}\sqrt3^2-\dots\right]\tag4
> $$
>
> ---
>
> $$
> I+\bbox[3px,border:1px solid black]{f+f'}=2^n[2(\text{Integer})]=2^{n+1}\cdot\text{Integer}\tag5
> $$
> $$
> I+1=2^{n+1}\cdot\text{Integer}\quad\checkmark\tag6
> $$

$(1)$ is just simple algebraic manipulation
$(2)$ is expanding via the Binomial Theorem ($I$ and $f$ are the integer and fraction parts)
$(3)$ is $(1)$ with the substitution $\sqrt3\mapsto-\sqrt3$; note that $\left(\sqrt3-1\right)^{2n}=\left(-\sqrt3+1\right)^{2n}$
$(4)$ is expanding via the Binomial Theorem
$(5)$ adding $(2)$ and $(4)$ cancels all of the terms with $\sqrt3$ to an odd power
$\phantom{\text{(5)}}$ and doubles all of the terms with $\sqrt3$ to an even power (these terms are integers)
$(6)$ since $0\lt\left(4-2\sqrt3\right)\lt1$, $f'\in(0,1)$ and by definition, $f\in[0,1)$
$\phantom{\text{(6)}}$ since $I+f+f'\in\mathbb{Z}$, we must have $f+f'=1$

---

Here is, in my experience, a more usual proof of this.

$\left(1\pm\sqrt3\right)^2=4\pm2\sqrt3$ are roots of $x^2-8x+4$. Therefore, the solution to the [linear recurrence equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)
$$
\begin{align}
u_n
&=8u_{n-1}-4u_{n-2}\\[3pt]
&=4(2u_{n-1}-u_{n-2})\tag7
\end{align}
$$
is
$$
\begin{align}
u_n
&=a\left(1+\sqrt3\right)^{2n}+b\left(1-\sqrt3\right)^{2n}\\[3pt]
&=a\left(4+2\sqrt3\right)^n+b\left(4-2\sqrt3\right)^n\tag8
\end{align}
$$
In particular, the sequence with $a=b=1$ starts out with
$$
u_0=2,u_1=8,u_2=56\tag9
$$
Note that $\left.2^{n+1}\,\middle|\,u_n\right.$ for $n=1$ and $n=2$. Then $(7)$ guarantees that
$$
\begin{align}
u_n
&=8u_{n-1}-4u_{n-2}\\[6pt]
&=8\cdot2^n\frac{u_{n-1}}{2^n}-4\cdot2^{n-1}\frac{u_{n-2}}{2^{n-1}}\\
&=2^{n+1}\left(4\frac{u_{n-1}}{2^n}-\frac{u_{n-2}}{2^{n-1}}\right)\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$
By induction, $(9)$ and $(10)$ show that $\left.2^{n+1}\,\middle|\,u_n\right.$ for all $n\ge1$.

Since $u_n\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\begin{align}
u_n
&=\left(1+\sqrt3\right)^{2n}+\overbrace{\left(1-\sqrt3\right)^{2n}}^{\text{in }(0,1)}\\[3pt]
&=\left\lceil\left(1+\sqrt3\right)^{2n}\right\rceil\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $(10)$ and $(11)$ show that
$$
\left.2^{n+1}\,\middle|\,\left\lceil\left(1+\sqrt3\right)^{2n}\right\rceil\right.\tag{12}
$$